# OracleParameter parameter constructor with VarChar object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
.Parameters.Add("Notes", OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar, 3000).Value = strBoxNotes
```

The Error produced says

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30519 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Overloads Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, direction As ParameterDirection) As OracleParameter': Argument matching parameter 'dbType' narrows from 'OracleType' to 'OracleDbType'.
    'Public Overloads Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, direction As ParameterDirection) As OracleParameter': Argument matching parameter 'direction' narrows from 'Integer' to 'ParameterDirection'.
    'Public Overloads Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, size As Integer) As OracleParameter': Argument matching parameter 'dbType' narrows from 'OracleType' to 'OracleDbType'.  ProjectName C:\Projects\frm_Main.vb 492 Active
```

When I peak at the definition

```
Public Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, direction As ParameterDirection) As OracleParameter <- The one the IDE thinks I want
Public Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, val As Object, dir As ParameterDirection) As OracleParameter
Public Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, size As Integer, val As Object, dir As ParameterDirection) As OracleParameter
Public Function Add(name As String, dbType As OracleDbType, size As Integer) As OracleParameter <-- The one I want
```

How do I force the IDE to choose the constructor I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parameters with parameter name in an explicit mode avoiding IDE choices like this:

```
 .Parameters.Add(name:="Notes", dbType:=OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar, size:=3000).Value = strBoxNotes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never would have guessed this.

Comment: Compiler have trouble in methods (with the same name) which have parameters as Object, that means will be every type.
In this case to chose the correct method you can call the method with named parameters.
Named parameters is so convenient to individuate the correct method (like in sql when you put where condition, the result is more faster). 
Named parameters is also so convenient in method with several Optional parameters, you can call this method with only parameters you are interested, you can change order of parameters etc.
However I’m glad my answer was helpful, you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Nuget version 19.6.0 of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

I found that `OracleType.VarChar` is now `OracleDbType.Varchar2` with this change you can use the parameters of the .Add method without names.

```
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Private Sub OPCode()
    Using cn As New OracleConnection("Your Connection String")
        Using cmd As New OracleCommand("Select * From Employees Where Name = @Name;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3000)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The Object Browser will you show you the parameters.